# Matrix Relative to Canonical Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{3}$ the linear map who's matrix

(relative to the bases 
$$
\begin{matrix} 2\\1\end{matrix}, \begin{matrix} 5\\3\end{matrix}$$ and 
$$
\begin{matrix} 1\\0\\1\end{matrix}, \begin{matrix}1\\1\\0\end{matrix},\begin{matrix} 1\\1\\1\end{matrix}$$)

Is

$$
\begin{matrix}7 & -3\\2 & 1\\8 & 0\end{matrix}
$$

**Find the matrix f relative to the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{3}$**

Comment: Please show your work so far. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I just don't know where to start

Comment: How do I find the canonical bases from the bases given

Comment: See Bernard’s answer, below. Use the fact that the columns of a change of basis matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the change of basis matrix: let $X$ the column vector of an element $u\in\mathbf R^2$, $X'$ the column vector of the same element in the new basis, $P$ the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to the new one in $\mathbf R^2$.

Similarly let $Y$, $Y'$ be the column vectors of $f(u)$  in the canonical basis and the new basis of $\mathbf R^3$ respectively, $Q$ the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to the new one in $\mathbf R^3$.

Finally let $A$ be the matrix of $f$ in the canonical bases, $A'$ its matrix in the new bases. We have 
$$X=PX',\quad Y=QY', \quad Y=AX$$

whence $QY'=APX'$, so $A'=Q^{-1}AP$, whence
$$A=QAP^{-1}.$$